# ng.getComponent($0) is returning null, Angular9

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I am trying to debug using new Ivy, in Angular9 default app.

`$0` is giving this : `<img _ngcontent-rmb-c11="" width="40" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9I==">`

But `cmp = ng.getComponent($0)` is giving `null`. What am i missing here.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Calling getComponent on   will return the instance of component associated with this DOM element that's why it's returning null. Use getOwningComponent to retrive component instance whose view contains the DOM element.

**Try this:**

```
cmp = ng.getOwningComponent($0);
```

Or

If you want to access Element then use

```
ng.getHostElement($0)
```

[For More Info](https://angular.io/api/core/global)